# Disable server side Javascript but not my Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I want to Disable server side Javascript but not my Greasemonkey so I can stop all the javascript/AJAX from the website so they can't detect I am using Greasemonkey ( no onclick validations to see if i really clicked and not just used my script etc ). But when I disable Javascript with a toggle addon for example it stops greasemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to generally disable script execution in the browser while not disabling the execution of userscripts, however, you can prevent site's scripts from execution by intercepting the scripts on the [`beforescriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute) event. You need to call the `Event.preventDefault()` method in your event handler and add the line `@run-at document-start` to your meta block of the userscript header.